# Question about the infimum of $|f(x)-x|$ , where $f(x)=x$, $x$ is a fixed point of the nonlinear equation.

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, supremum-and-infimum

I am trying to check if the following property holds for fixed points:
Suppose:

$ f(x)= x $ is given, with solution $x = \theta \gt 0 $

I would like to show :

$ \forall \epsilon \in (0,1), \forall x : 1/\epsilon > |x -\theta| > \epsilon => \inf_x |f(x) - x | > 0  $.

I am not sure if this property holds for the particular case. I would be grateful is someone can give me any idea on the topic.

The best I was able to come up with was that due to the fact that the function is continuous it does not change sign within some vicinity of $\theta$. Because $f(x) = x $ has a solution for $x=\theta$ then we can find $ |f(x) -x|<\epsilon $, when $ x \to \theta $, so $ x-\epsilon<f(x) $ and since $\epsilon$, can be chosen arbitrary small and $x>0$ than $ 0<x-\epsilon<f(x)$ hold, for a small $\epsilon$ vicinity of $\theta$.

Thanks,

Comment: What if $f(x_n)=x_n$ for a sequence of values of $x_n$ converging to $\theta$?

Comment: Hi, I just made an update of my question, perhaps this is what you are proposing? Actually I have continuous values. But the idea is quite the same. What bothers me is the fact that the annuls I am looking at becomes very large as $\epsilon \to 0 $.

Comment: Stefan Hansen made an effort to make your problem look nicer, and then you put it back to looking like crap. Why?

Comment: I just updated it, I am sorry if I did something wrong.

Comment: Anyway, are you not aware that it is possible for a continuous function to vanish at, say, all and only the points $1,1/2,1/3,1/4,\dots$ and zero? If not, try to come up with an example.

Comment: Ok I understood you wrong, what is the argument with the sequence?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "what is the argument with the sequence?", but my point is that if you have a continuous function $f$ such that $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$ and for a sequence of $x$-values converging to zero, then the function may change sign in every neighborhood of zero, no matter how small the neighborhood.

Comment: What I meant is the following:  suppose we have a continuous function. And $f(x_0) > 0$ than for $|x-x_0|<\delta => |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$ , since epsilon is positive, and $f(x_o) $ is positive by construction then setting $f(x_0)=2\epsilon$ gives : $f(x_0)/2<f(x)$ . Therefore, in some $\delta$ vicinity of $x_0$ the function does not change it sign. This is a quite natural fact, perhaps my explanation was a bit messy, for which I apologize. The correct question would be, what properties the function $f(x)$ should have in order to fulfill the condition I have posed in my question.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is **continuous** and the equation $f(x)=x$ has a **unique** solution $x=\theta$, then the statement is true: 
$$\inf\{ |f(x) - x |: \epsilon \le |x-\theta|\le \epsilon^{-1} \} > 0,\quad \text{for all } \ 0<\epsilon<1$$
Indeed, since the set $\{ x : \epsilon \le |x-\theta|\le \epsilon^{-1} \} $ is compact, the continuous function $|f(x)-x|$ attains its minimum on this set. The minimum is positive since $f(x)\ne x$ for $x\ne \theta$.